# Get the user details woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site. The users need to log in to purchase. Users have added their details to their account directly (Dashboard > Users). The user role is Customer.

I need to fetch the company address from the customer profile. I have used the below code:

```
<?php $users= get_user_meta(  $item['user_id'], 'billing_company', true ); 
    echo $users;
?>
```

But it is now showing the company address. it is not showing anything.

What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: So `$item['user_id']` is not working… Have you tried to `echo $item['user_id']` to see if you get something…

Comment: Not working either. Just to clarify, I have customers registered and their address is in their account. I need to get that.

Comment: Where are you using this code.. Is it in backend or in frontend? Where exactly? is it the woocommerce dashboard template?

Comment: I am actually adding this to a plugin code. I am using the plugin to generate PDF order invoice and I need to print the user details who have ordered the product. There is no billing address in the order itself. http://take.ms/KxHKS I need to import that directly from the user account.

Comment: What are the available arguments? Can you have the **order ID** in some way at minima where you are adding this code?